# List index out of range - for loop with JSON string

Tags: python

I'd like to get help with a function I got stuck on. It sends a request to extract all messages from the Discord server as JSON. Then, I use a for loop and if to check which messages have a mention of my account to add them to the "Unreplied" dict.

The error message here is:

```py
line 32, in sms_retrieve_others
    if value["mentions"][0]["id"] == atuserid:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

However, the result of this for loop is successful despite the exit code 1 which is the only problem here.

UPD: a sample of the JSON string:

```json
{
    "id": "sample",
    "type": 19,
    "content": "pretty good",
    "channel_id": "sample",
    "author": {
        "id": "sample",
        "username": "sample",
        "avatar": "sample",
        "avatar_decoration": null,
        "discriminator": "sample",
        "public_flags": 0
    },
    "attachments": [],
    "embeds": [],
    "mentions": [
        {
            "id": "sample",
            "username": "sample",
            "avatar": "sample",
            "avatar_decoration": null,
            "discriminator": "sample",
            "public_flags": 0
        }
    ],
    "mention_roles": [],
    "pinned": false,
    "mention_everyone": false,
    "tts": false,
    "timestamp": "2022-10-15T14:07:15.411000+00:00",
    "edited_timestamp": null,
    "flags": 0,
    "components": [],
    "message_reference": {
        "channel_id": "sample",
        "guild_id": "sample",
        "message_id": "sample"
    },
    "referenced_message": {
        "id": "sample",
        "type": 19,
        "content": "pretty good",
        "channel_id": "sample",
        "author": {
            "id": "sample",
            "username": "sample",
            "avatar": "sample",
            "avatar_decoration": null,
            "discriminator": "sample",
            "public_flags": 0
        },
        "attachments": [],
        "embeds": [],
        "mentions": [
            {
                "id": "sample",
                "username": "sample",
                "avatar": "sample",
                "avatar_decoration": null,
                "discriminator": "sample",
                "public_flags": 0
            }
        ],
        "mention_roles": [],
        "pinned": false,
        "mention_everyone": false,
        "tts": false,
        "timestamp": "2022-10-15T13:12:27.686000+00:00",
        "edited_timestamp": null,
        "flags": 0,
        "components": [],
        "message_reference": {
            "channel_id": "sample",
            "guild_id": "sample",
            "message_id": "sample"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code:

```py
import requests
import json

unreplied = {}

def sms_retrieve_others(channelid, atuserid):
    r = requests.get(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelid}/messages", headers=auth)
    jsonn = json.loads(r.text)
    for value in jsonn:
        if value["mentions"][0]["id"] == atuserid:
            unreplied.update({value["id"]: value["content"]})
            print(unreplied)
```

Comment: Please update your question with a small sample from `r.text`

Comment: You need to deal with the possibility that `mentions` is an empty list.

Comment: @Mark and that there even is a `"mentions"` key. Not an immediate issue here, but for thoroughness.

Comment: also... you could write this `unreplied.update({value["id"]: value["content"]})` just as: `unreplied[value["id"]] = value["content"]`

Comment: @Chris I feel there will be 'mentions' key thatswhy OP is getting index error else he will be getting keyerror

Comment: Or maybe, their code always errors out with `IndexError` first and never manages to get to a `KeyError`?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check that the `json` has the format you assume it has:

```py
def sms_retrieve_others(channelid, atuserid):
    r = requests.get(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelid}/messages", headers=auth)
    jsonn = json.loads(r.text)
    for value in jsonn:
        if 'mentions' in value:
            mentions = value["mentions"]
            if mentions:
                first = mentions[0]:
                if 'id' in first:
                    if first["id"] == atuserid:
                        unreplied.update({value["id"]: value["content"]})
                        print(unreplied)
```